# After selecting a row another rows get selected automatically of UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

i am developing a application which has table view, 
each table view cell contains only Label,
i had set cell accessory type to CheckMark,
if i selects a row the checkmark appears 
everything is working up to this

But when i selects a row and scroll downs a table view then CheckMark appears at other rows,
so please help me

i have attached the code below

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
  let selectRow = self.MytableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
  var can: Candy
  if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView{
     can = self.filteredCandy[indexPath.row]
  }else{
     can = self.candies[indexPath.row]
  }
let name = "\(can.firstName) \(can.lastName)"
 if selectRow.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None{
    selectRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    selectRow.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    DataStorageManager.sharedInstance.guests.append(name)
 }else{
    selectRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    DataStorageManager.sharedInstance.guests == DataStorageManager.sharedInstance.guests.filter(){$0 != name}   
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add code cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved above problem by adding following code into cellForRowAtIndexPath method of UITableView

```
if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView{
can = self.filteredCandy[indexPath.row]
}else{
can = self.candies[indexPath.row]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing logically mistake which is you are going to make checkmark to new cell but you didn't make Un checkmark for last selected row. So please implement my logic.
First of all make a global variable like

```
 let selectedRow = 0

And then implement this one 

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let selectedIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(forItem: selectedRow, inSection: 0)
        let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)! as UITableViewCell

        selectedCell.accessoryType = .None

let selectRow = self.MytableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
  var can: Candy
  if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView{
     can = self.filteredCandy[indexPath.row]
  }else{
     can = self.candies[indexPath.row]
  }
let name = "\(can.firstName) \(can.lastName)"
 if selectRow.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None{
    selectRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    selectRow.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    DataStorageManager.sharedInstance.guests.append(name)
 }else{
    selectRow.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    DataStorageManager.sharedInstance.guests == DataStorageManager.sharedInstance.guests.filter(){$0 != name}   
    }

selectedRow = indexPath.row
}
```

Comment: but i want it for multiple selection

Comment: i will let you know only login, store all selected row's index in array and check it in cellforrowatindexapath method is it exits in array then make it check mark otherwise make it .None

Comment: @ Dharmbir Singh   Please give me example if you have

Comment: @RaviG No i dont have but i can help you show me your code

Comment: func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var a: Int!
            if tableView == self.searchDisplayController?.searchResultsTableView{
                a = self.filteredCandy.count
            }else{
            a = self.candies.count
            }
        return a
    }

Comment: @RaviG Please implement this one https://agilewarrior.wordpress.com/2012/02/10/how-to-configure-uitableview-for-multirow-selection/

Comment: give me your email i will mail you

Answer (score 0):

Here most of TableViewCell problems I have solved, Like when clicking the **cell button** after scrolling the remaining rows may be changed and when selecting at **didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath** the row, after scrolling the remaining rows may be selected. So I created an app to solve those problems.   Here adding GitHub code [Find the code](https://github.com/SreekanthGudisi/UITableView)

- In the first screen, click on a red button and just scroll down you can't see other cells are affected automatically in UITableViewCell.
- Clicking on **didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath** in the first screen you can go to details screen that's the second screen, in that screen after selecting a row other rows won't be selected automatically in UITableViewCell.